# Cannot upload files in IE or firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, selenium-webdriver, upload, protractor

Currently I am using this method to upload files:

```js
uploadImage: function(fileToUpload) {
  //clicking the add photo button
  var addMediaModal = element.all(by.css('#px-select-photo')).first();
  browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', addMediaModal.getWebElement());
  browser.actions().mouseMove(addMediaModal).click().perform();
  var path = require('path');
  //the file to upload
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload)
  var elm = $('input[type="file"]');
  browser.executeScript('var input = $("input:file"); input[0].removeAttribute("class");');
  elm.sendKeys(absolutePath);

},
```

This works only in Chrome.  Firefox and IE open the upload window and just hangs while chrome does everything behind scenes.

```html
<span class="ui-button-text"><span class="upload-title">Add Photos</span>
<input style="cursor: pointer;" id="px-select-photo" name="file" class="me-fileUpload" data-label="AddPhotos" data-filetypes="jpg|jpeg|gif|png" data-invalidmessageresource="ErrorUnsupportedPhotoFormat"
multiple="" type="file">
</span>
```

Comment: @alecxe This is the code I was referring to.  I also had elm set to #px-select-photo but it also was not working in any browser besides chrome.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the `class` of the input element? Also, what happens when you click the `addMediaModal` element? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe this was an attempt of using the other code I saw hoping for a fix. the addMediaModal button clicks on the add photo button without adding that click the windows upload box stays open.

Comment: In general, you need to avoid having the browser upload popup being opened. What if you would not click the `addMediaModal` button and just send the keys to the appropriate file input? Thanks.